# Doxygen, generate only callgraph

Tags: doxygen, call-graph, doxygen-wizard

I tried Doxygen on a sample project from GIT. I was able to create documentation with navigation panel but I need doxygen to generate only the callgraph. Is is possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I say no. To generate the graph Doxygen needs to process your whole project anyhow. You could try disabling options on some outputs but essentially it wouldn't save you much time.

There is some XML output that you may be able to analyze and feed into the graphing engine, but again, to get that output you have to let Doxygen churn away.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Set only `CALL_GRAPH             = YES` and turn off all other options.